# Niemeier Lattice

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I want to learn about Niemeier lattice and Leech lattice in it. I will be pleased if some one could introduce some books or Lecture notes to me.

Comment: Have you looked in Conway and Sloane's *Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups*?  It's a good first reference for just about anything having to do with the objects in the title.  Certainly Niemeier and Leech are in there...

Comment: I need some basics. I have looked at the book but it is a kind of some results about these lattices. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Without knowing more about what you are hoping for, it's hard to give an answer.  If you need detailed information about Niemeier lattices, it may be difficult to find sources that are substantially more accessible than Conway and Sloane (although perhaps I am overlooking something).  Maybe you would be interested in the book *From error-correcting codes through sphere packings to simple groups* by Thompson?  It doesn't mention Niemeier lattices, but it's a very readable introduction to the Leech lattice, and it is good preparation for Conway and Sloane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard reference is Conway and Sloane. If this  is too much, you could try 
Wolfgang Ebeling's book
"Lattices and codes
A course partially based on lectures by F. Hirzebruch." Advanced Lectures in Mathematics. Friedr. Vieweg & Sohn, Braunschweig, ISBN: 3-528-06497-8. This covers Venkov's classification of Niemeier lattices, and some properties of the Leech lattice

Comment: Oops, I was indeed overlooking something.  Ebeling is a good suggestion - it has the advantage of developing things systematically from scratch, while Conway and Sloane is mainly a collection of reprinted papers, with some expository chapters thrown in.  If you want to work in this area, eventually you will need to come to terms with Conway and Sloane, but you should think of it as a reference book rather than a textbook.  There's an enormous amount of valuable information in it, and some parts are quite accessible, but it was never meant to be read straight through.

Comment: Neat, I'd never heard of Ebeling's book. I have to say that "developing things systematically from scratch" is more to my style than Conway and Sloane's compendious tome of examples and results. (For me it is a very valuable reference, but I can learn only a little bit each time I open it.) I look forward to reading Ebeling.

Comment: Note that the AMS distributes Ebeling's book and other Vieweg titles including some English translations.   As Henry Cohn comments, the Conway-Sloane volume is better viewed as a reference source.  